# parallelStream vs stream.parallel

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have been curious about the difference between `Collections.parallelStream()` and `Collections.stream().parallel()`.  According to the Javadocs, `parallelStream()` tries to return a parallel stream, whereas `stream().parallel()` returns a parallel stream.  Through some testing of my own, I have found no differences.  Where does the difference in these two methods lie? Is one implementation more time efficient than another?  Thanks.

Comment: Short answer: no difference.  Long answer: noooooooo difference.  They're just aliases for each other.

Comment: I just find something , I do not know whether it represents the difference of them? please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44013553/when-calculate-ab-why-parallel-not-work-but-parallelstream-could

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Even if they act the same *at the moment*, there is a difference - at least in their documentation, as you correctly pointed out; that might be exploited in the future as far as I can tell.

At the moment the `parallelStream` method is defined in the `Collection` interface as:

```
default Stream<E> parallelStream() {
    return StreamSupport.stream(spliterator(), true);
}
```

Being a default method it could be overridden in implementations (and that's what `Collections` inner classes actually do).

That hints that even if the default method returns a parallel Stream, there could be Collections that override this method to return a `non-parallel Stream`. That is the reason the documentation is probably the way it is.

At the same time *even* if `parallelStream` returns a sequential stream - it is still a `Stream`, and then you could easily call `parallel` on it:

```
  Collections.some()
       .parallelStream() // actually sequential
       .parallel() // force it to be parallel
```

At least for me, this looks weird.

It seems that the documentation should somehow state that after calling `parallelStream` there should be no reason to call `parallel` again to force that - since it might be useless or even bad for the processing.

**EDIT**

For anyone reading this - please read the comments by Holger also; it covers cases beyond what I said in this answer.

Comment: It’s hard to imagine a scenario where it is reasonable that a stream *source* denies parallel processing for the stream, without knowing what actual operations will be chained. Perhaps, if it is rolling its own implementation of the `Stream` API, but then, it is in full control of what happens when `.parallel()` is called…

Comment: @Holger I did not get the *might be sequential part* either. I also admit that it would be very cool to see a collection that will not benefit at all from parallel processing.

Comment: Well, an empty collection would never benefit from parallel processing, however, since there is no guaranty about the number of threads anyway, there is no harm in still letting `isParallel()` return `true`. Likewise, a stream over a singleton collection without a `flatMap` operation will never use a second thread, still, there is no harm in `isParallel()` returning `true`. This also applies to all streams whose underlying spliterator returns `null` in `trySplit`; without something like `sorted` or `flatMap`, it doesn’t matter whether you call `.parallel()`; it won’t have any effect.

Comment: @Holger I was more thinking of a *theoretical in-future-added* collection, but your input makes complete sense!

Comment: Just thinking it to its end, if you have a source that doesn’t support any parallel processing, there is still no reason why `thatSource .parallelStream() .sorted(). otherOps()` should be forbidden to use parallel processing, once the internally used array has been populated, as at that point, the processing is entirely detached from the source. I have the feeling that the sentence stems from a time when the interaction between the source and the stream implementation was still in motion.

Comment: @Holger there are times I don't actually get your answers, but certainly try to come to those to revise them... by internal array you meant the `sorted` operation here that would copy the elements from the `Spliterator` to the `Sink` (array or `ArrayList`) right? Sorry to bring this up so late

Comment: Yes, exactly, the temporary storage used by `sorted()`, whether array or not, is independent from the source collection, so it can be processed in parallel, even if the source tries to deny it. Likewise, if a spliterator’s `trySplit` method returns `null`, the Stream implementation *could* turn to a buffering strategy like `AbstractSpliterator.trySplit` does. Actually, it would make more sense if the Stream did this instead of `AbstractSpliterator`…

Answer (score 10):

There is no difference between `Collections.parallelStream()` and `Collections.stream().parallel()`.  They will both divide the stream to the extent that the underlying spliterator will allow, and they will both run using the default `ForkJoinPool` (unless already running inside another one).

Answer (score 4):

```
class Employee {
    String name;
    int salary;

    public int getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(int salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public Employee(String name, int salary) {
        this.name = name;
        this.salary = salary;
    }
}
class ParallelStream {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        long t1, t2;
        List<Employee> eList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            eList.add(new Employee("A", 20000));
            eList.add(new Employee("B", 3000));
            eList.add(new Employee("C", 15002));
            eList.add(new Employee("D", 7856));
            eList.add(new Employee("E", 200));
            eList.add(new Employee("F", 50000));
        }

        /***** Here We Are Creating A 'Sequential Stream' & Displaying The Result *****/
        t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Sequential Stream Count?= " + eList.stream().filter(e -> e.getSalary() > 15000).count());

        t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Sequential Stream Time Taken?= " + (t2 - t1) + "\n");

        /***** Here We Are Creating A 'Parallel Stream' & Displaying The Result *****/
        t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Parallel Stream Count?= " + eList.parallelStream().filter(e -> e.getSalary() > 15000).count());

        t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Parallel Stream Time Taken?= " + (t2 - t1));

        /***** Here We Are Creating A 'Parallel Stream with Collection.stream.parallel' & Displaying The Result *****/
        t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("stream().parallel() Count?= " + eList.stream().parallel().filter(e -> e.getSalary() > 15000).count());

        t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("stream().parallel() Time Taken?= " + (t2 - t1));



    }

}
```

I had tried with all three ways **`.stream(),.parallelStream() and .stream().parallel().`** with same number of records and able to identify timing taken by all three approach.

Here i had mentioned O/P of same.

```
Sequential Stream Count?= 300
Sequential Stream Time Taken?= 18
Parallel Stream Count?= 300
Parallel Stream Time Taken?= 6
stream().parallel() Count?= 300
stream().parallel() Time Taken?= 1
```

I am not sure,but as mentioned in O/P time taken by **`stream().parallel()`** is 1/6th of **`parallelStream()`**.

Still any experts suggestions are mostly welcome.

Comment: if you run the stream separately, could see almost same time for the streams.

Comment: @sagar-gangwal 

Try to change loop size from 100 to 5_000_000 then you will see another result like below:


`Sequential Stream Count?= 15000000`
`Sequential Stream Time Taken?= 102`
`Parallel Stream Count?= 15000000`
`Parallel Stream Time Taken?= 64`
`stream().parallel() Count?= 15000000`
`stream().parallel() Time Taken?= 97`

Comment: Remember that Java Runtime uses JIT, so benchmarking things like this is a bit trickier.

Comment: loop size 100, 000 result

**1st call:-**

`Sequential Stream Count?= 300000
Sequential Stream Time Taken?= 52

Parallel Stream Count?= 300000
Parallel Stream Time Taken?= 40

stream().parallel() Count?= 300000
stream().parallel() Time Taken?= 29`


**2nd call:-**

`Sequential Stream Count?= 300000
Sequential Stream Time Taken?= 25

Parallel Stream Count?= 300000
Parallel Stream Time Taken?= 47

stream().parallel() Count?= 300000
stream().parallel() Time Taken?= 37`