# when calculate a^b why parallel not work but parallelStream could

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-8, java-stream, reduce

I want to calculate a^b , e.g. 2^30,

```
public long pow(final int a, final int  b)
```

first I used this manner

```
return LongStream.range(0, b).reduce(1, (acc, x) -> a * acc); // 1073741824
```

Got right result. Then I want to calculate it parallelly, so naturally I changed it to

```
return LongStream.range(0, b).parallel().reduce(1, (acc, x) -> a * acc); // 32
```

but in this case the result is just `32`. Why?

So for supporting parallel I changed it again

```
return Collections.nCopies(b,a).parallelStream().reduce(1, (acc, x) -> acc * x); // 1073741824
```

in this case it works.

So what's wrong with `parallel` manner?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[reduce](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/LongStream.html#reduce-long-java.util.function.LongBinaryOperator-) requires that the supplied function be [associative](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Associativity).  Your function `(acc, x) -> a * acc` does not satisfy the requirement and thus violates the contract.

To be associative, the function must satisfy `(x op y) op z == x op (y op z)` for any x, y and z.  But for your function, `(x op y) op z = x*a^2` while `x op (y op z) = x * a`.

Furthermore, the first parameter supplied to reduce must be an identity with respect to the accumulator function.  So it must be true that `1 op x == x` for any x.  But that also doesn't hold for your accumulator function since `1 op x == a`.

The correct way to do this is:

```
LongStream.range(0, b).map(x -> a).reduce(1, (u, v) -> u * v);
```

This is guaranteed to work correctly whether the stream is parallel or sequential.

Comment: I still confused, if it is not  associative why the first manner -- without parallel -- it works? And I even tried to simulate this result -- 32 , and I cannot reproduce it. My code is https://gist.github.com/zhugw/248f2942ce955877a18a2f3f4fa4c68e I think under the hood the parallel is implemented by this way.

Comment: It happens to work because the current sequential implementation **happens** to not actually depend on either of the 2 requirements (associativity and identity).  Parallel implementation does depend on both.  But there is no guarantee that your first sample will continue to work.  Alternate implementations of java standard library or even future versions of JDK may well be implemented in a way that would break it.

Comment: hi, I have some new discoveries. please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

After tracing source code, I finally knew why the result is 32.

```
return LongStream.range(0, b).parallel().reduce(1, (acc, x) -> a * acc); // 32
```

Related source code

```
   // java.util.stream.ReduceOps.ReduceTask#onCompletion
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(CountedCompleter<?> caller) {
        if (!isLeaf()) {
            S leftResult = leftChild.getLocalResult();
            leftResult.combine(rightChild.getLocalResult()); // here to combine
            setLocalResult(leftResult);
        }

    }

    // java.util.stream.TerminalOp
    @Override
    public void combine(ReducingSink other) {
        accept(other.state);
    }
    @Override
    public void accept(long t) {
        state = operator.applyAsLong(state, t); // (acc, x)
    }
```

because actually not used `x` in lambda

```
(acc, x) -> a * acc;
```

so the actual effect is like this

```
leftResult.combine(2);
```

[Online demo](https://codepad.remoteinterview.io/GJZTOJGDDO) to simulate this phenomenon.